# What does Airplane Mode do on a iPad without cellular functionality?

Tags: ipad, wifi, bluetooth, airplane-mode

What does Airplane Mode do on an iPad without cellular functionality? It doesn't seem to disable either BlueTooth or WiFi - when I press the Airplane Mode button on my iPad, both of those channels remain on and functional. Morever, I can't see any option to allow Airplane Mode to disable these channels. So what does it turn off?

(Despite the similar titles, this is not a duplicate of [What's the point of airplane mode on a wifi-only iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123578/whats-the-point-of-airplane-mode-on-a-wifi-only-ipad), because of changes in how the iPad function since that question was asked. That question is asking "What *unique* functionality does Airplane Mode deliver that you can't do manually?", and apparently applied to an earlier version of the iPad for which Airplane Mode did disable BlueTooth and WiFi. I'm asking literally what does the toggle actually do in modern versions.)

iPad v 15.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first time you use it, it turns off all radios except for Bluetooth.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204234

However, since they are allowed on planes you can be in Airplane mode and turn bluetooth or WiFi back on.  It remembers that, and the next time you go into airplane mode it does not turn off the ones you turned on manually.

So on a non-cellular iPad, initially it would turn off the wifi and bluetooth radios.   You can manually turn them back on, and if you do, the next time Airplane mode won't turn off anything.